# Change target bundle indenfier change other target

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have 4 target in my project and each target is an different application, application share all source and they differ each other for a little section.
For do that simply I add an preprocessor define in build setting of the target which represent my application, I change also the bundle indentifier and the bundle display name.

The strange behavior if that when I try to change an bundle indentifier of a target sometimes (yes no all time) other target change also their bundle identifier and bundle display name.

What's  wrong?

Comment: Could you explain yourself a little bit more? It's not that your english is so bad but you described it in a misunderstandable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand from your question that you want 4 targets with different bundle identifiers and bundle display names.

You should create a `<target>-Info.plist` for each of the targets. Do this to create a plist for each target:

- Right click a plist and duplicate the file. Rename it to the name of one target.
- Select project > target > Build Settings, type plist on the search box, you'll see the element `Info.plist File`. Change its value to point at the plist file you created.
- Open that plist and change the `Bundle Name`, `Bundle Display Name`, `Bundle Identifier` to whatever you like.